# Remove some commits permanently from forked master repo and sync with main repo

Tags: git, github

Main Repo - A

I forked a repo B from main repo A.

I wrote some code and accidentally pushed it in forked repo (B) - master branch and then i reverted the commit as well.

Now, whenever i create a branch from forked repo (B) , i am getting those 2 commits (the one which i created and reverted). Is there any way to get rid of two commits and overwrite the entire master branch and sync it with the parent/Main repo.

Or is there any way to simply ignore this fork and create another fork from the same id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to get rid of two commits

Yes:

```
git reset --hard master~2
```

If you want the fork to look like that too:

```
git push --force
```